# One-sided hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference

Please, check the following problem from the exam:

[image: exam problem]

Could you check the following logic:

1. H$_{0}$: difference in the ratings = 0
2. H$_{a}$: difference in the ratings > 0, because human resources manager wants to determine an increase in the ratings
3. Based on (2) I conclude that it is right-sided test and positive critical value of the test statistics is needed.

Am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: Should have self study tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct the HR manager is testing for a positive change and therefore a one tail test is appropriate. However, the equation is

x=mean(Before-After)

And therefore we are testing for a negative result (i.e. rating after are better than before - not very intuitive) and therefore a negative critical value is required at the 5% confidence level.

Comment: Is this a t test?  Not specified in the exam problem.  If it is you must know the degrees of freedom (should be pretty obvious) to determine which of the 4 answers is correct if any.

Comment: You could get the wrong answer if you get the degrees of freedom wrong or if you pick the wrong number of tails (1-tailed vs 2-tailed) test and a third wrong answer if you get both degrees of freedom and number of tails wrong.

Comment: I imagine those answering this may not even know about DoF. T-test is implied by the sample size.

Comment: So @MorganBall have we told the OP enough now so that he arrives at the right answer (maybe because he knows about df and what test is intended?  I like your answer but whether or not I am hinting in a comment or an answer I worry that I am telling too much?

Comment: It seems that based on the sample size of the employees it follows that t-test is not appropriate hear and we should not use t-test. Right?

Comment: I think you should be able to google that one ;)

Comment: MorganBall, Google tells me that I should use nonparametric test. Is it right? Could you propose the name of the test?

Comment: Your not given the distribution of responses so there is no way of knowing whether it is parametric or not. I would assume given a small sample size the examiner was expecting the t-test to be used.

Comment: @user190519 Don't be stubborn take MorganBall's advice when the sample size is small and data are normal the t test is preferred to the z test because the fact that the sample variance must be used the t takes this extra variability in account.  There are analogue nonparametric tests but under normality they are not preferable to the t test .